# Is there general formula for the inverse of this matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-numbers

For some natural number $\alpha>2$ we set $\zeta=e^{\frac{2i\pi}{\alpha}}$. Let's consider
$\alpha$-by-$\alpha$ matrix and choose its entries to be $\zeta^{(i-1)(j-1)}$ in the

$i$-th row and $j$-th column.
$$\begin{bmatrix}
\zeta^{0} & \zeta^{0} & \zeta^{0} & \dots &\zeta^{0}\\
\zeta^{0} & \zeta^{1} & \zeta^{2} & \dots &\zeta^{\alpha-1}\\
\zeta^{0} & \zeta^{2} & \zeta^{4} & \dots &\zeta^{2(\alpha-1)}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\zeta^{0} & \zeta^{(\alpha-1)} & \zeta^{2(\alpha-1)} & \dots &\zeta^{(\alpha-1)^2}
\end{bmatrix}$$
I would like to find the inverse of this matrix for given $\alpha$. However I have very little experience with matrices and I don't even know if there is a chance of finding a solution to this problem. The only thing I noticed is that the inverse matrix will always have $\frac{1}{\alpha}$ in first row and first column since $\sum_{m=0}^{\alpha-1}\zeta^{nm}=0$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}_+$ 
I would be very thankful for any help.

Comment: One way to do this is to try a few small $n$ and see if there's an obvious pattern

Comment: To be honest It takes me really a lot of time to find these inverses even for $\alpha=3$ and I thought that maybe you will be able to find some obvious solution before I spent hours trying to calculate them.

Comment: If you can compute determinants of submatrices, then you may find a solution with the adjugate of a matrix: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is that if we call this matrix $M$, then $M^{-1} = M^\dagger/\alpha $.

To see that this is true, consider that each $m_{jk} = \zeta^{jk}$. The elements of $M^\dagger$ will then be $\{M^\dagger\}_{jk} = m_{kj}^
* = \zeta^{-kj}$. Now let's multiply these together:
$$
\{M^\dagger M\}_{jk} = \sum_{\ell = 0}^{\alpha - 1}  \zeta^{-j\ell}\zeta^{k\ell} = \sum_{\ell = 0}^{\alpha - 1}\left[\zeta^{k-j}\right]^\ell = \begin{cases}\alpha & j = k \\ 0 & j\ne k\end{cases}
$$
In other words, $M^\dagger M = \alpha I$. The result then follows.

Incidentally, this is the [discrete Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DFT_matrix) matrix, though you may already know this.

Comment: Brilliant. Didn't think to use the additional hint for the definition of $\zeta$.